# retrieve mysql output from django 'manage.py sql appname'

Tags: mysql, django, database-design, sqlite

I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve the MySQL code for DB setup. Right now it's using sqlite for output when I run 'manage.py sql management'

See below:

```
MB-PR0:users jg$ python manage.py sql management
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "management_service" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "service_name" varchar(32) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "management_employee_services" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "employee_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "service_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "management_service" ("id"),
    UNIQUE ("employee_id", "service_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "management_employee" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "first_name" varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    "gmail_active" bool NOT NULL,
    "employee_status" bool NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "management_note" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "note_name" text NOT NULL,
    "employee_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "management_employee" ("id")
)
;
COMMIT;
```

Is there a way to have this output as MySQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change your settings.py file to use
   MySQL
2. run manage.py sql management
3. Change your Settings.py file back.

I think that should work. I've never tried it though.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like basic SQL syntax. Can't you use this script by just running it via commandline?

```
$ mysql <my_db_name> -u<user_name> -p < mysql.sql
```

(This is using commandline redirecting)
You will be asked for your password after pressing enter, then the script is executed.

Before that you can check if it is installed:

```
$ mysql -V
```

..or do you have phpmyadmin or the MySQL "IDE" installed? At least from the last one you could execute the script from a GUI desktop application, if needed.